# Not able to generate Dual Y-axis chart report in excel using NPOI 2.6.2 & C#

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core, charts, npoi

Am not able to generate chart report excel with Secondary Y-Axis below is the code I have already developed for Primary Y-axis but my requirement is to create secondary Y-axis as well which is am not able to achieve with NPOI. Could you please help me out achieving this requirement and also guide me how to achieve with below mentioned code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KvuB.png)

using NPOI.SS.UserModel; using NPOI.SS.UserModel.Charts; using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel; using System.IO; using NPOI.SS.Util; using Newtonsoft.Json;
private void GenerateSingleAxisReport() { try { IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); ISheet sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Profile");
// Sample data for the chart
// Replace jsonText with your actual JSON string
string jsonText = File.ReadAllText("C:\GIT\WpfApp1\WpfApp1\file1.json");
sheet.CreateRow(0).CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Time");
sheet.GetRow(0).CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("Feed W");
sheet.GetRow(0).CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("V1 Level Fraction");
sheet.GetRow(0).CreateCell(3).SetCellValue("T1 Temperature");
sheet.GetRow(0).CreateCell(4).SetCellValue("T1 Vapor");
List<DataRecord> dataRecords = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataRecord>>(jsonText);

```
 // Now you can access the data
 int i = 1;
 foreach (var record in dataRecords)
 {
     sheet.CreateRow(i).CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(record.Time);
     sheet.GetRow(i).CreateCell(1).SetCellValue(record.FeedW);
     sheet.GetRow(i).CreateCell(2).SetCellValue(record.V1LevelFraction);
     sheet.GetRow(i).CreateCell(3).SetCellValue(record.T1Temperature);
     sheet.GetRow(i).CreateCell(4).SetCellValue(record.T1Vapor);
     i++;
 }
 IDrawing patriarch = sheet.CreateDrawingPatriarch();
 IClientAnchor anchor = patriarch.CreateAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 15, 15);

 IChart chart = patriarch.CreateChart(anchor);
 // Add Title to Chart
 chart.SetTitle(&quot;Combined Trend Chart&quot;);  // Set the title here
 IChartLegend legend = chart.GetOrCreateLegend();
 legend.Position = LegendPosition.Bottom;

 // Scatter Chart
 IScatterChartData&lt;double, double&gt; data = chart.ChartDataFactory.CreateScatterChartData&lt;double, double&gt;();

 // Use a category axis for the bottom axis.
 IChartAxis bottomAxis = chart.ChartAxisFactory.CreateCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.Bottom);
 IValueAxis leftAxis = chart.ChartAxisFactory.CreateValueAxis(AxisPosition.Left);
 leftAxis.Crosses = AxisCrosses.AutoZero;

 // Series 1
 IChartDataSource&lt;double&gt; xs1 = DataSources.FromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, 60, 0, 0));
 IChartDataSource&lt;double&gt; ys1 = DataSources.FromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, 60, 1, 1));
 IScatterChartSeries&lt;double, double&gt; series1 = data.AddSeries(xs1, ys1);
 series1.SetTitle(&quot;V1 Level Fraction&quot;);

 // Series 2
 IChartDataSource&lt;double&gt; xs2 = DataSources.FromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, 60, 0, 0));
 IChartDataSource&lt;double&gt; ys2 = DataSources.FromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, 60, 2, 2));
 IScatterChartSeries&lt;double, double&gt; series2 = data.AddSeries(xs2, ys2);
 series2.SetTitle(&quot;T1 Temperature C&quot;);

    chart.Plot(data, bottomAxis, leftAxis);

 using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(&quot;BasicLineChartReport.xlsx&quot;, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
 {
     workbook.Write(stream);
 }

 MessageBox.Show(&quot;Excel report generated successfully.&quot;);
```

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show($"Error generating Excel chart report: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
}
}